# Is it possible to add VB to an Excel sheet from POI?

Tags: java, excel, vba, apache-poi

Does anyone know if it's possible to add VB to an Excel document, from within Java? I basically want to add a pivot table to a sheet, and set some of it's properties dynamically. I know that I can access the pivot table settings from VB, but not directly from POI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done something similar, where I've created a spreadsheet with VBA *in advance* using Excel. I then load it using POI, populate the values and then save it out again. Thus I get a spreadsheet with the populated values and the preconfigured VB/macros etc.

Perhaps you need to create your VBA in advance, and it will read its dynamic properties from the sheet. You can then populate these properties at will.